# What's with James K?

Tags: discussion, users

I'm used to 'reinstate Monica' user names, but now I've seen someone called 'xxx supports James K' - what's the story? Should I be 'Michael Harvey didn't vote for Brexit'? Isn't it a bit grandstanding?

[image]

Comment: [*last seen 39 secs ago*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/24231/james-k?tab=profile) – he's still alive :)

Comment: Also, where did you see that username? [I can't find it on our site.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=support)

Comment: Why does he need support?

Comment: I saw it yesterday on ELL about 5 minutes before posting the question. It was a question OP.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That's an unregistered user and I forgot they don't show up in the search.

Comment: It's a new user; perhaps they saw all those 'X supports Y' usernames and though 'Who can I support? Well, perhaps the top user; we all like to support winners.'

Comment: I thought maybe he had offended somebody or broken 
 some SE rule or other.

Comment: *uses mod powers* Not that I know of.

Comment: Any views on my wider point about using usernames to state a position in a controversy being 'grandstanding'? I actually find it annoying.

Comment: General stance on Stack Exchange is that it's accepted. Myself, I got used to it. As long as I can identify the original user from the username, I'm good.

Comment: Why didn't you vote for Brexit? Do you now feel you stood on the wrong side of history?

Comment: Since we have been out of the EU for 14 days as I write this, it's a bit soon to say which is the "right side" of "history" (whatever that means). Were the Social Democrats in the Weimar Republic on the "right" or "wrong" side of history? Depends who you asked in 1933 and 1945.

Comment: I didn't vote for Brexit because, like 48.11% of those who voted in the referendum, I believed (and still do) that the United Kingdom would be better off in the EU than outside it. Better off materially and culturally. I have been a supporter of the European project for most of my conscious life. On a personal level, my bullshit antennae were sent into full-on mode by the utterly detestable Nigel Farage (lately Trunp's poodle) as well as the Tory Brexit cheerleaders (Gove, etc). Brexit was and is a mainly Tory project. I am a lifelong card-carrying member of the Labour Party.

Comment: I was teasing you, but thank you for writing a serious reply. I appreciate your answer on many levels.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey But we got are sovrenty back.

Comment: @PrimeMover is that satirical spelling?

Comment: @JavaLatte - The kind of UK people who write below-the-line comments under newspaper articles (Daily Mail and Daily Express mainly) tend to spell like that also greengrocers' apostrophes, random mid-sentence capitalisation, 'are' for 'our', 'off' for 'of', 'loose' for 'lose', 'defiantly' for 'definitely', mix up their/there/they're, your/you're, and more... knuckle draggers, and mostly Fascist little Englanders.

Comment: The person concerned about grandstanding is the person who puts "Woke" in the middle of his username.

Comment: @FeliniusRex - fair point. +1 comment vote.